# how to get new lines inside a text column

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store lyrics of some songs in a database, for example:
`blue sky
deep sea
hot sun
...`

When I paste this text in a text column the result is:
`blue sky deep sea hot sun`

How can I do it keeping line breaks as above, and also keeping the ability to fetch this data in a html div or textarea with the same lines ?

Comment: how about <p> blue sky </p> <p> deep sea </p> .... 
Or blue sky <br> deep sea <br> ?

Comment: @minhhn2910, I suppose that would be ok for the second step (fetching the data inside html), but I need to keep lines inside mysql also

Comment: What do you mean by keep lines inside mysql ? it's just a string,

Comment: You can also add \n to your string, so after u fetch data from mysql, php will print <br> for you ?

Comment: @minhhn2910, ok it's a string, but a string inside a `text` field. So is it impossible to have new lines inside mysql table?

Comment: It's the ability of the mysql client you use. And you never say what client are you using in the question. You can write your own php file to act as a client to paste the lyrics, automatically detect \n and append <br> to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Would be best if you can reformat the lyrics and append a line break eg: \n at the end of each line and submit it straight to your database without escaping the line break characters.

Comment: could you give me an example pls, for the second part: `submit it straight...`

Comment: Once you format your lyrics with line breaks, get the lyric reference and insert as normal like how it's done to insert new data to your mysql database.

Comment: lyric reference ?

Comment: I mean the variable that holds lyrics string should be used to insert new data into your mysql database.

Comment: part of my post - `When I paste this text in a text column...` so copy-paste is my method to insert data into database.

Comment: Oh, then you have to manually insert lots of line breaks manually and edit the lyrics on any preferable editor before pasting them into mysql columns.

Comment: Can't believe? Manually? Line breaks are already there, why I need to write them again manually?

Comment: Cause copy&pasting seem not the best approach then try it out by appending the line breaks manually and see the output.

Comment: ok I added `\n` and `<br>` at the end of each line and it's ok when I output this content inside a html div, but still there is no new lines inside mysql table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149838/discussion-between-sharkes-monken-and-bonaca).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "." delimiter to justify newline. The $lyric will appear as it is once stored inside your database. Whenever you want to retrieve the lyrics to a song then use a function to split the string into array when it reaches the "." delimiter.

Have a look at the code below:

```
$lyric = "blue sky.deep sea.hot sun.";
$lyricArr = explode(".", $lyric);

echo $lyric . '</br></br>';

foreach($lyricArr as $verse){
    print $verse . '</br>';
}
```

Comment: That's not my situation. Imagine you copied a lyrics in the clipboard and want to paste them in a table column (field type - `text`), and want to see new lines inside tha pasted text, and also want to se new lines inside fetched this content inside html div.